How is the $\pi_1(X)$ action on higher homotopy groups visible in $\Pi_\infty(X)$

It is well known that $\pi_1(X)$ acts on all the higher homotopy groups, and this action can be seen in several different ways see this question. I have recently started working with the fundamental groupoid and its higher analogues. 
For specifity, let's work with $\Pi_\infty(X,x)$ the pointed infinity fundamental groupoid of $X$ (and so it has a single object $x$). My questions is whether (and if so how) it is possible to understand the action of $\pi_1(X, x)$ on $\pi_n(X,x)$ in this context. If I understood correctly, if $\gamma\in \pi_1(X,x)$ and $\alpha\in\pi_n(X,x)$ we can view these in $\Pi_\infty(X,x)$ as elements of $Aut(x)$ and of $Aut(Id_x^{(n)})$ (where $Id_x^{(n)}$ is the identity $n$-morphism of the identity $n-1$ morphisms). By whiskering there is a "conjugation" action $\gamma\dot\alpha$, which I wish to show is the "classical" action. 
The problem is that my understanding of the infinity fundamental groupoid is still too shaky to show this precisely and with confidence. If anyone knows if my intution is even true, that would be great. Thanks a lot.

I think you want section 3 here taking $\mathbf{X}=\Omega X$ and using that when $X$ is connected there is an equivalence $B \Omega X \simeq X$. I don't have time to make this precise atm but hopefully it helps. I think that you're intuition is right. The left action is corepresented as a functor $(\Omega X,Spc)$ by the basepoint but you want conjugation which is like the "double action" category in that paper.

@AndresMejia I sadly am not able to understand this paper, I will try to study a bit more and thank you for the reccomendation. To me it seems like it refers to the action of X on itself when X is a topological group, not on the $\pi_1$ action on higher homotopy groups.

you take $\Omega X$ which is an $\mathbb E_1$ ring. This is covered in higher algebra :)
